# Notification Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am developing audio player. I can play any music on audio player when I play music than it create notification for music.

Audio player working prefect for playing music, but my problem is that when I press on notification icon it show me null pointer exception to jumping playerActivity, I know uri is null due to destroying Activity but I can't understand how to handle this problem.

Here is my code

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListner(new AudioDeatailAdapter.OnItemClckListner() { 
    @Override
    public void OnClick(ArrayList<Audio> audioArrayList,int possition) {
        String media = audioArrayList.get(possition).getData();

        Intent intent = new Intent(AudioActivity.this,PlayerAudioActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("uri",media);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

when press on item it get uri and send into intent to PlayerAudio Activity PlayerAudio Activity `getdata()` is function that is used to get data from intent

```
public void getData() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    try {
        sourceUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("uri"));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      sourceUri = intent.getData();
    }

    File file = new File(sourceUri.toString());
    if (file != null && file.length() != 0) {
        String filename = file.getName();
        txt_name.setText(filename);
        txt_name.setSelected(true); 
    }
}
```

and inside on start() function service start and play music and also show notification when i press notification it show null pointer exception on this function

```
File file = new File(sourceUri.toString();

if (file != null && file.length() != 0) {
    String filename = file.getName();
    txt_name.setText(filename);
}
```

here is my notifactin code

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
    prerationListner.prepared();
    this.handler.postDelayed(seekBarRunable, 100);

    mp.start();
    //notification
    Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerAudioActivity.class);
    notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
            .setTicker(songTitle)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Playing")
            .setContentText(songTitle);
    Notification not = builder.build();
    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
}
```

here is my logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{studio.freeapp.com.jplayer/studio.freeapp.com.jplayer.activity.PlayerAudioActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
    at studio.freeapp.com.jplayer.activity.PlayerAudioActivity.getData(PlayerAudioActivity.java:319)
    at studio.freeapp.com.jplayer.activity.PlayerAudioActivity.onCreate(PlayerAudioActivity.java:113)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

I know Source uri is null, how to handle this problem?

here is my solution i reached on problem with all of reply i read carefully comments than think where is mistake i found solution with help... All friends comments thanks a lot everyone

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
    prerationListner.prepared();
    this.handler.postDelayed(seekBarRunable, 100);

    mp.start();
    //notification
    Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerAudioActivity.class);
    notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notIntent.putExtra("uri", sourceUri);
    notIntent.putExtra("playerpos", true);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
            .setTicker(songTitle)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Playing")
            .setContentText(songTitle);
    Notification not = builder.build();
    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
}
```

Comment: Provide your logcat.

Comment: where is your notification code ,post that

Comment: Please do it by this way.

`Uri.parse(intent.getExtra.get("uri"));`

Comment: thank you all of you i fix it the problem was that when press on notification than i was forget to send uri with notification i appreciated all of your reply i was reach to problem with all of ur comments Thanks a lot every one

Comment: @heisen-Breg NotTdar Fenil Patel lot of thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an object via `intent` and trying to capture `String` on reception.

You can implement the `Serializable` `interface` in the `class` `Audio` and then pass object instances in the intent extra using the putExtra(Serializable)

Example:

```
Audio media = audioArrayList.get(possition);
Intent intent = new Intent(AudioActivity.this,PlayerAudioActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uri",media);

//On reception

sourceUri = Uri.parse(intent.getSerializableExtra("uri"));
```

Comment: i appreciated your help thanks a lot its done right now